# Golang json marshalling returns empty after sleeping in subroutine

Tags: go, pointers, memory, marshalling, goroutine

Go newbie here. I am trying to create a http handler that drops the main routine if the client drops the connection by using the request context. Inspiration is from here: https://go.dev/blog/context/google/google.go

The general structure of my code is to kick off a subroutine to retrieve a slice of struct pointers and pass them back to the main routine via a channel. The main routine has a select on client request context and the data-retrieval subroutine.

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/JRjoFNw5Gko

Code:

```
package handlers

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    // "gitlab.com/mbsloth14/learn-go/monorepo/products/data"
)

type Product struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
}

type Products []*Product

var productList = []*Product{
    {
        ID: 1,
    },
    {
        ID: 2,
    },
}

type ListProducts struct {
    log *log.Logger
}

func NewListProducts(log *log.Logger) *ListProducts {
    return &ListProducts{log: log}
}

func (lp *ListProducts) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    p, retrieveProductsErr := lp.listProducts(req.Context())

    if retrieveProductsErr != nil {
        http.Error(rw, retrieveProductsErr.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    lp.log.Printf("ListProductsHandler: retrieved %d products\n", len(p))
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(rw)
    err := encoder.Encode(p)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(rw, "Server failed to encode results. Returning empty list.", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        lp.log.Println("ListProductsHandler: failed to encode results", err)
    }
}

func (lp *ListProducts) listProducts(ctx context.Context) (Products, error) {
    resultsChan := make(chan Products)
    defer close(resultsChan)

    go func() {
        lp.log.Println("ListProductsHandler: retrieving products")
        // time.Sleep(5 * time.Second) // <------- PROBLEMATIC LINE!
        resultsChan <- getProducts()
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        lp.log.Println("ListProductsHandler: client canceled request")
        <-resultsChan
        return Products{}, ctx.Err()
    case p := <-resultsChan:
        return p, nil
    }
}

// Mock DB/API call
func getProducts() Products {
    return productList
}
```

I am testing if the select statement is effective by adding a sleep statement in the subroutine to simulate database delay. Regardless of this delay, the handler always shows that 2 products are retrieved. However, when the subroutine sleeps, encoder writes an empty string back to the client whereas the entire slice gets properly marshaled back to the client when there is no sleep.

Any idea would be super appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Because the function `getProducts` does not support cancelation, there's no value in calling `listProducts` over calling `getProducts` directly from the `ServeHTTP` method.   The select statement always waits for anonymous goroutine to complete because all branches of the select receive from `resultsChan`.

Comment: See https://go.dev/play/p/Xk5KBUA_1M1 for code that follows the outline of the code in the blog post.